# KineticJS: group cloned items in order to drag them

Tags: kineticjs

How can I group cloned shapes and images, so that I can drag them together? I made the cloned images to be on top of the cloned rectangles. Do I have to create new `Kinetic.Group` each time I drag a rectangle? Is there another alternative for makig them drag, without grouping them?

I'm using kineticJS to perform drag and drop as many cloned items as I want, from one layer to another, this is the code I wrote until now http://jsfiddle.net/GLFxF/34/ I don't know how I should do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic.Groups are the best method to drag a set of shapes/images.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7BkR7/

When you drag+drop  one of your cloned items, you can use `clone.on("dragend"` to have the cloned item join whichever group (rectangle) that it was dropped into.

Assume all your rectangle containers have been added to a containers[] array.

Then you can use this `dragend` function to have the clone `moveTo` any container its dropped into:

```
clone.on("dragend",function(){
    var pos=this.getAbsolutePosition();
    var x=pos.x;
    var y=pos.y;
    var hit=-1;
    for(var i=0;i<containers.length;i++){
        var c=containers[i];
        var cx=c.x();
        var cy=c.y();
        if(x>=cx && x<=cx+c.width() && y>=cy && y<=cy+c.height()){
            hit=i;
        }
    }
    if(hit>=0){
        var container=containers[hit];
        this.x(x-container.x());
        this.y(y-container.y());
        this.moveTo(container);
    }else{
        this.x(x);
        this.y(y);
        this.moveTo(layer);
    }
});
```

Comment: When I clone a rectangle and drag and drop it in the container, can I make it be a group, so that when images are dropped join it?

Comment: Sure.  If you have an original group containing your rectangle (as in my code above), you can clone that group and your rect will be cloned also:  layer.add(group.clone({x:newX,y:newY}));
layer.draw();